# How to generate a large database from an existing sample database like NorthWind and maintain the relationships between tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-generate

I am working with the POSTGRESQL NorthWind Database ([Link](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/sample-data/northwind/))
I want to create additional rows in the existing database, while maintaining the relationships between the tables. I saw the MD5 hash function to create rows in a single table, however that doesnt help me much with creating related rows in the other tables.

Any resources or suggestions (including code) snippets would be really helpful, since I have tried to find resources but I have come up short on relevant ones.

Many Thanks,
PJ

Comment: You would do as you would in any database where you are adding data. First create the parent row then the child row(s).

Comment: I get that, my intention for asking this question was whether there is any automated ways of just specifying the columns and we get the generated rows?